# Crystal report concatenate fields in group footer to show comma separated

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have records in detail section as

Sedol.    Currency  price

Abns67     USD      67.3
Abns67     EUR      43.5

I am grouping my records based on sedol. Now I want to show in group footer as below

Abns67      EUR,USD   43.5,67.3

HOW TO Achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a detail level formula to concatenate the details to a glocal string variable.
Use a Group Header formula to reset that variable.
Use a Group Footer formula to display the result.

Comment: Thank you for response. Could you please formulate the same as I still dint get it